# How to integrate maven framework with Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

In order to integrate and run the Selenium Maven project on Jenkins `2.73.3`, I set the option(s) as the following images:

[image: "Build" configuration]

Notice `Goals and options` with `clean install`; nothing else selected/checked, but `Enable triggering of downstream projects`.

[image: Maven configuration]

Notice `Install automatically` is unchecked.

Jenkins project built successfully without opening any browser that shows any activity.

Please, let me know if there is/are any project setting(s) to solve this issue; i.e.: can we see the Web application run on browser as it does when it's run by the Maven project.

Comment: Something went wrong trying to attach images: try using "the image button" from the post-editor's tool bar. Be sure to [include the gist](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) *in* the question proper.

Comment: @Mohammad please study [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Jenkins from services means you are using installable Jenkins version which not allow opening of any UI invocation.

You need to use `jenkins.war`

You can download war from below URL:

https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/war/

Use below command to start Jenkins server

```
java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=9090
```